# Use two for loops in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a dictionary, which records how many drum beats in every measure:

```
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 3, 13: 4, 14: 4, 15: 3, 16: 5, 17: 5, 18: 6, 19: 4, 20: 4, 21: 5, 22: 4, 23: 6, 24: 6, 25: 6, 26: 7, 27: 6, 28: 7, 29: 4, 30: 7, 31: 8, 32: 6, 33: 7, 34: 8, 35: 8, 36: 9, 37: 8, 38: 12, 39: 7, 40: 10, 41: 8, 42: 14, 43: 13, 44: 13, 45: 16}
```

For example, there is a drum beat in first measure, and there are 16 drum beats in 46th measure.

Then I have another dictionary, which records the score(0~3) the player plays in every drum beat:

```
{0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 1, 11: 1, 12: 0, 13: 3, 14: 3, 15: 1, 16: 1, 17: 3, 18: 1, 19: 3, 20: 1, 21: 3, 22: 1, 23: 3, 24: 3, 25: 2, 26: 2, 27: 2, 28: 2, 29: 2, 30: 3, 31: 3, 32: 2, 33: 2, 34: 3, 35: 1, 36: 1, 37: 3, 38: 0, 39: 1, 40: 2, 41: 3, 42: 3, 43: 0, 44: 2, 45: 2, 46: 1, 47: 2, 48: 1, 49: 1, 50: 1, 51: 2, 52: 1, 53: 2, 54: 3, 55: 1, 56: 1, 57: 0, 58: 0, 59: 3, 60: 2, 61: 0, 62: 0, 63: 1, 64: 0, 65: 2, 66: 1, 67: 1, 68: 1, 69: 0, 70: 3, 71: 3, 72: 3, 73: 2, 74: 1, 75: 1, 76: 1, 77: 1, 78: 1, 79: 2, 80: 2, 81: 2, 82: 2, 83: 0, 84: 0, 85: 1, 86: 0, 87: 1, 88: 2, 89: 3, 90: 1, 91: 2, 92: 2, 93: 3, 94: 3, 95: 2, 96: 1, 97: 0, 98: 3, 99: 3, 100: 1, 101: 0, 102: 3, 103: 3, 104: 1, 105: 3, 106: 0, 107: 2, 108: 0, 109: 1, 110: 0, 111: 1, 112: 0, 113: 2, 114: 0, 115: 2, 116: 0, 117: 1, 118: 3, 119: 1, 120: 3, 121: 3, 122: 3, 123: 1, 124: 1, 125: 0, 126: 2, 127: 0, 128: 3, 129: 3, 130: 1, 131: 0, 132: 3, 133: 2, 134: 1, 135: 1, 136: 0, 137: 1, 138: 0, 139: 3, 140: 3, 141: 1, 142: 2, 143: 3, 144: 1, 145: 2, 146: 0, 147: 0, 148: 0, 149: 1, 150: 0, 151: 3, 152: 0, 153: 1, 154: 0, 155: 3, 156: 2, 157: 3, 158: 1, 159: 0, 160: 1, 161: 1, 162: 1, 163: 2, 164: 3, 165: 0, 166: 1, 167: 1, 168: 2, 169: 0, 170: 1, 171: 0, 172: 1, 173: 1, 174: 1, 175: 0, 176: 1, 177: 1, 178: 2, 179: 3, 180: 0, 181: 1, 182: 3, 183: 0, 184: 3, 185: 0, 186: 1, 187: 0, 188: 1, 189: 2, 190: 0, 191: 1, 192: 0, 193: 0, 194: 0, 195: 2, 196: 1, 197: 0, 198: 2, 199: 1, 200: 0, 201: 2, 202: 2, 203: 0, 204: 1, 205: 3, 206: 1, 207: 0, 208: 0, 209: 1, 210: 0, 211: 0, 212: 0, 213: 3, 214: 0, 215: 1, 216: 1, 217: 0, 218: 3, 219: 0, 220: 2, 221: 0, 222: 3, 223: 1, 224: 0, 225: 3, 226: 0, 227: 0, 228: 1, 229: 0, 230: 2, 231: 1, 232: 0, 233: 3, 234: 0, 235: 2, 236: 1, 237: 0, 238: 2, 239: 3, 240: 3, 241: 0, 242: 1, 243: 0, 244: 2, 245: 0, 246: 2, 247: 0, 248: 1, 249: 0, 250: 0, 251: 1, 252: 0, 253: 1, 254: 0, 255: 1, 256: 1, 257: 0, 258: 0, 259: 1, 260: 1, 261: 0, 262: 1, 263: 0, 264: 1, 265: 0, 266: 3, 267: 0, 268: 3}
```

For example, The player got three points in first drum beat, and got three points in 269th drum beat.

Then I need to calculate the average score in every measure the player got. 
For example, the player got 3/1 = 3 points(average) in first measure, and got (3+3)/2 = 3(average) in second measure.

I know I need to use two for loops, but I don't know how to start with, can anyone help me? Thanks

More examples:

```
The average score in first measure the player got is 3/1 = 3,
The average score in second measure the player got is (3+3)/2 = 3,
The average score in third  measure the player got is (3+3)/2 = 3,
The average score in fourth measure the player got is (1+2)/2 = 1.5,
The average score in fifth  measure the player got is (3+2)/2 = 2.5,
The average score in sixth  measure the player got is (2+1+1)/3 = 1.33,
The average score in seventh measure the player got is (0+3)/2 = 1.5,
The average score in eighth  measure the player got is (3+1)/2 = 2
,etc.
```

Comment: for 3rd measure it will be  (3+3+3)/2, Right?

Comment: You'll need to better explain the the problem, add more example

Comment: for 3rd measure it will be (3+3)/2

Comment: Why? What's the logic behind that?

Comment: @PeterChen (3+3)/2. Here one `3` belongs to the previous average and next to current beat. Right?

Comment: This is a really simple problem, you just need to improve your explanation...

Comment: I am not sure what exactly do you want. But you can simplify your code using `zip()`. Also, dicts are not ordered by default, you will have to sort the values based on key.

Comment: In first dictionary, the value of the key '0' is '1', which means there is a drum beat in first measure, and the value of the key '1' is '2', which means there are two drum beats in second measure. And in the second dictionary, it records the score the player got in every drum beat. So in first measure, because there is only a drum beat(recorded in first dictionary), so the average score in first measure the player got is 3/1 = 3, and the average score in third measure the player got is (3+3)/2 = 3, because there are two drum beats in third measure(recorded in first dictionary)

Comment: And because there are 16 drum beats in 46th measure. So the player got (3+0+3+0+1+0+1+0+1+1+0+0+1+1+0+1)/16 = 0.8125(average score) in 46th measure.

Comment: Do you expect gaps, or why do you use dictionaries instead of simple lists?

Comment: yeah, this problem can be solved by list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Num_NumOfBeats_Mapping = {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 3, 13: 4, 14: 4, 15: 3, 16: 5, 17: 5, 18: 6, 19: 4, 20: 4, 21: 5, 22: 4, 23: 6, 24: 6, 25: 6, 26: 7, 27: 6, 28: 7, 29: 4, 30: 7, 31: 8, 32: 6, 33: 7, 34: 8, 35: 8, 36: 9, 37: 8, 38: 12, 39: 7, 40: 10, 41: 8, 42: 14, 43: 13, 44: 13, 45: 16}
result = {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 1, 11: 1, 12: 0, 13: 3, 14: 3, 15: 1, 16: 1, 17: 3, 18: 1, 19: 3, 20: 1, 21: 3, 22: 1, 23: 3, 24: 3, 25: 2, 26: 2, 27: 2, 28: 2, 29: 2, 30: 3, 31: 3, 32: 2, 33: 2, 34: 3, 35: 1, 36: 1, 37: 3, 38: 0, 39: 1, 40: 2, 41: 3, 42: 3, 43: 0, 44: 2, 45: 2, 46: 1, 47: 2, 48: 1, 49: 1, 50: 1, 51: 2, 52: 1, 53: 2, 54: 3, 55: 1, 56: 1, 57: 0, 58: 0, 59: 3, 60: 2, 61: 0, 62: 0, 63: 1, 64: 0, 65: 2, 66: 1, 67: 1, 68: 1, 69: 0, 70: 3, 71: 3, 72: 3, 73: 2, 74: 1, 75: 1, 76: 1, 77: 1, 78: 1, 79: 2, 80: 2, 81: 2, 82: 2, 83: 0, 84: 0, 85: 1, 86: 0, 87: 1, 88: 2, 89: 3, 90: 1, 91: 2, 92: 2, 93: 3, 94: 3, 95: 2, 96: 1, 97: 0, 98: 3, 99: 3, 100: 1, 101: 0, 102: 3, 103: 3, 104: 1, 105: 3, 106: 0, 107: 2, 108: 0, 109: 1, 110: 0, 111: 1, 112: 0, 113: 2, 114: 0, 115: 2, 116: 0, 117: 1, 118: 3, 119: 1, 120: 3, 121: 3, 122: 3, 123: 1, 124: 1, 125: 0, 126: 2, 127: 0, 128: 3, 129: 3, 130: 1, 131: 0, 132: 3, 133: 2, 134: 1, 135: 1, 136: 0, 137: 1, 138: 0, 139: 3, 140: 3, 141: 1, 142: 2, 143: 3, 144: 1, 145: 2, 146: 0, 147: 0, 148: 0, 149: 1, 150: 0, 151: 3, 152: 0, 153: 1, 154: 0, 155: 3, 156: 2, 157: 3, 158: 1, 159: 0, 160: 1, 161: 1, 162: 1, 163: 2, 164: 3, 165: 0, 166: 1, 167: 1, 168: 2, 169: 0, 170: 1, 171: 0, 172: 1, 173: 1, 174: 1, 175: 0, 176: 1, 177: 1, 178: 2, 179: 3, 180: 0, 181: 1, 182: 3, 183: 0, 184: 3, 185: 0, 186: 1, 187: 0, 188: 1, 189: 2, 190: 0, 191: 1, 192: 0, 193: 0, 194: 0, 195: 2, 196: 1, 197: 0, 198: 2, 199: 1, 200: 0, 201: 2, 202: 2, 203: 0, 204: 1, 205: 3, 206: 1, 207: 0, 208: 0, 209: 1, 210: 0, 211: 0, 212: 0, 213: 3, 214: 0, 215: 1, 216: 1, 217: 0, 218: 3, 219: 0, 220: 2, 221: 0, 222: 3, 223: 1, 224: 0, 225: 3, 226: 0, 227: 0, 228: 1, 229: 0, 230: 2, 231: 1, 232: 0, 233: 3, 234: 0, 235: 2, 236: 1, 237: 0, 238: 2, 239: 3, 240: 3, 241: 0, 242: 1, 243: 0, 244: 2, 245: 0, 246: 2, 247: 0, 248: 1, 249: 0, 250: 0, 251: 1, 252: 0, 253: 1, 254: 0, 255: 1, 256: 1, 257: 0, 258: 0, 259: 1, 260: 1, 261: 0, 262: 1, 263: 0, 264: 1, 265: 0, 266: 3, 267: 0, 268: 3}
sum = 0
start_value = 0
for n in range(len(Num_NumOfBeats_Mapping)):
    i = Num_NumOfBeats_Mapping[n]
    for s in range(start_value,start_value+i):
        sum += result[s]
    Average_result.append(sum/i)
    sum = 0
    start_value += i
print Average_result
```

Average_result is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
beats = {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 4, 11: 2, 12: 3, 13: 4, 14: 4, 15: 3, 16: 5, 17: 5, 18: 6, 19: 4, 20: 4, 21: 5, 22: 4, 23: 6, 24: 6, 25: 6, 26: 7, 27: 6, 28: 7, 29: 4, 30: 7, 31: 8, 32: 6, 33: 7, 34: 8, 35: 8, 36: 9, 37: 8, 38: 12, 39: 7, 40: 10, 41: 8, 42: 14, 43: 13, 44: 13, 45: 16}

score = {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 2, 9: 2, 10: 1, 11: 1, 12: 0, 13: 3, 14: 3, 15: 1, 16: 1, 17: 3, 18: 1, 19: 3, 20: 1, 21: 3, 22: 1, 23: 3, 24: 3, 25: 2, 26: 2, 27: 2, 28: 2, 29: 2, 30: 3, 31: 3, 32: 2, 33: 2, 34: 3, 35: 1, 36: 1, 37: 3, 38: 0, 39: 1, 40: 2, 41: 3, 42: 3, 43: 0, 44: 2, 45: 2, 46: 1, 47: 2, 48: 1, 49: 1, 50: 1, 51: 2, 52: 1, 53: 2, 54: 3, 55: 1, 56: 1, 57: 0, 58: 0, 59: 3, 60: 2, 61: 0, 62: 0, 63: 1, 64: 0, 65: 2, 66: 1, 67: 1, 68: 1, 69: 0, 70: 3, 71: 3, 72: 3, 73: 2, 74: 1, 75: 1, 76: 1, 77: 1, 78: 1, 79: 2, 80: 2, 81: 2, 82: 2, 83: 0, 84: 0, 85: 1, 86: 0, 87: 1, 88: 2, 89: 3, 90: 1, 91: 2, 92: 2, 93: 3, 94: 3, 95: 2, 96: 1, 97: 0, 98: 3, 99: 3, 100: 1, 101: 0, 102: 3, 103: 3, 104: 1, 105: 3, 106: 0, 107: 2, 108: 0, 109: 1, 110: 0, 111: 1, 112: 0, 113: 2, 114: 0, 115: 2, 116: 0, 117: 1, 118: 3, 119: 1, 120: 3, 121: 3, 122: 3, 123: 1, 124: 1, 125: 0, 126: 2, 127: 0, 128: 3, 129: 3, 130: 1, 131: 0, 132: 3, 133: 2, 134: 1, 135: 1, 136: 0, 137: 1, 138: 0, 139: 3, 140: 3, 141: 1, 142: 2, 143: 3, 144: 1, 145: 2, 146: 0, 147: 0, 148: 0, 149: 1, 150: 0, 151: 3, 152: 0, 153: 1, 154: 0, 155: 3, 156: 2, 157: 3, 158: 1, 159: 0, 160: 1, 161: 1, 162: 1, 163: 2, 164: 3, 165: 0, 166: 1, 167: 1, 168: 2, 169: 0, 170: 1, 171: 0, 172: 1, 173: 1, 174: 1, 175: 0, 176: 1, 177: 1, 178: 2, 179: 3, 180: 0, 181: 1, 182: 3, 183: 0, 184: 3, 185: 0, 186: 1, 187: 0, 188: 1, 189: 2, 190: 0, 191: 1, 192: 0, 193: 0, 194: 0, 195: 2, 196: 1, 197: 0, 198: 2, 199: 1, 200: 0, 201: 2, 202: 2, 203: 0, 204: 1, 205: 3, 206: 1, 207: 0, 208: 0, 209: 1, 210: 0, 211: 0, 212: 0, 213: 3, 214: 0, 215: 1, 216: 1, 217: 0, 218: 3, 219: 0, 220: 2, 221: 0, 222: 3, 223: 1, 224: 0, 225: 3, 226: 0, 227: 0, 228: 1, 229: 0, 230: 2, 231: 1, 232: 0, 233: 3, 234: 0, 235: 2, 236: 1, 237: 0, 238: 2, 239: 3, 240: 3, 241: 0, 242: 1, 243: 0, 244: 2, 245: 0, 246: 2, 247: 0, 248: 1, 249: 0, 250: 0, 251: 1, 252: 0, 253: 1, 254: 0, 255: 1, 256: 1, 257: 0, 258: 0, 259: 1, 260: 1, 261: 0, 262: 1, 263: 0, 264: 1, 265: 0, 266: 3, 267: 0, 268: 3}

beatCounter = 0

for k in beats: #for each key in beats
    temp = 0    #reset temp to 0
for i in range(beats[k]):  #for the number of beats in each measure 
    temp += (score[beatCounter]) #add scores for that measure
    beatCounter += 1
print("Average of measure", k + 1, " is", temp/beats[k])
```

and beatCounter keeps track of where in the score dict you are

Comment: the result is not what I want, the result I want is that the average score in each measure the player got. For example, the average score in first measure the player got is score[0]/beats[0] = 3, the average score in second measure the player got is (score[1]+score[2])/beats[1] = 3, the average score in third measure the player got is (score[3]+score[4])/beats[2] = 3, the average score in fourth measure the player got is (1+2)/2 = 1.5 ((score[5]+score[6])/beats[3]), which means the count of numerator is denominator.

Comment: That code does print out the average score in each measure did you run the code?